# start other Android apps at specific activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I want to start other applications (any app, not just apps made by me) at specific activities. The information about the package name and the activity are obtained programmatically during runtime and is stored in a flattened string that contains the package name and the class name. I later do this to launch the app at the selected activity.

```
 Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent();
 LaunchIntent.setClassName(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(info_string).getPackageName(), ComponentName.unflattenFromString(info_string).getClassName());
 startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

But this doesn't work...The app launches at it's main activity. I saw a method called:

```
Intent.setClass(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls);
```

I tried to use it but i couldn't find any way to get the package context of another app.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Show manifest of another app, and which actiivty you are calling

Comment: the information for the package name and class name are obtained programmatically. It is not one of my own apps that I want to start. I'm talking about any app.

Comment: So you can't. You can only launch specific activity if that is defined as exported and as View.

Comment: First, it is only possible to start activities that are exported. 
Second, even if the activity is exported, it is very possible that the developer of the app did not expect other apps to randomly start that activity. For example, the activity may be expecting certain action strings, `Uri` values, or `Intent` extras that you will not be supplying. IOW, starting an activity in the way that you are describing is likely to crash, either in your app or the other app.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch that *specific* activity, consider sending the package name via **Bundle**, with the intent you use to launch that activity. Later in that activity, you can launch that app, using this string which contains the package name.

**EDIT:** You say that you get the package name and class name programmatically. So just *separate* the two and then do the following:

Use an intent to launch that activity using the class name. For the package name part:

```
    Intent channelIntent =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ClassName.class);//Replace with the name of the class of the specific activity.
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("app_package", package_name);//replace package name with "com.x.y" -Your package name
                    channelIntent.putExtras(b);
                    channelIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(channelIntent);
```

Within that activity, use

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String app_pkg = b.getString("app_package");
```

to retreive that package name. Then launch that app from that activity using the package name.

Comment: i'm sorry but I didn't quite get that...Can you explain a little?

Comment: what you are describing is the same as:

Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(info_string).getPackageName());
     startActivity( LaunchIntent );

and it just launches the app using the package name without defining the activity. unless i am missing something